# Drupal site communication with other site

Tags: users

Hello I have a Drupal 7 site.
I want users to login without using the drupal form.
I will silently send username and password credentials from another site and when users click the link to my drupal site they will be already logged in.
So how to communicate with drupal login and send the details of the user from another site or maybe a browser plugin or a PC application etc.

Comment: Do you want to create unique usernames for all those who follow link to your drupal or just use one User say Guest for all ? If its the former case then you will end up with lot of data in user s table.

Comment: Does the other site use Drupal too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly complicated thing to do, but the "go to" module for handling integration with third-party sites is the [services module](http://drupal.org/project/services).